# A particular usage of "en"

Tags: en

Consider the following sentence:

Léna pense qu'elle **en** a rencontré un.

I think it's saying that "Lena thinks she's met one". But what's  the purpose of "en" here? Why not just say:

Léna pense qu'elle a rencontré un.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, "en" is called a "partitive" because it singles out a part (that is an entity) of a larger set as in "she believes aliens exist and thinks she met one (of them)".

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know what's the role of "en" in this one:
J'en faisais des cauchemars horrible

Comment: Could you please provide a larger context (for example the one you quote this sentence from)?

Comment: Sure. Here's a link to the clip:
https://youtu.be/-6lSl88KE5g
(sorry the story is a bit disturbing :( )
Here's what I hear:
Vous êtes au courant
pour Lucy Clarsen ? Qui ça ? Une fille qui travaillait dans ce bar, là,
le Lake Pub. Bref, elle rentrait chez elle, et un type l'a sauvagement agressée
dans le tunnel. Il lui a bouffé l'estomac. Ça recommence, on dirait, comme il y a sept ans.
(something?????) J'en faisais des cauchemars horribles...

She says something before "j'en" that I don't understand.

Comment: In this case, "en" refers back to the content of the nightmares without mentioning it again (something like "I had horrible nightmares (ABOUT the attack in the tunnel").

Comment: Awesome, thanks.